# CSS: Sub-menu expanders ([+]/[-]) jump up and down upon open and close due to a CSS porting glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, jqtree

On [this website](http://www.shlomifish.org/__Beta-kmor/) (tested in close-to-latest
Opera, Firefox and Google Chromium on Mageia Linux 3 Cauldron and on Firefox on my Arch Linux VM), the expanders/[+] signs of the navigation menu on the left get shifted a little
upwards and downwards when the sub-menu is expanded/collapsed. That's not the case if the expander in question the last one in the sub-tree (for example, under "Humour" →
"Recommendations").

Why and how can it be avoided? Is it because of the different character in the text? I tried setting it to monospace - it did not help.
It works fine [here](http://www.shlomifish.org/), but the CSS and generated
DOM are different.

(**Note:** [this](http://www.shlomifish.org/) is my permanent site while [this](http://www.shlomifish.org/__Beta-kmor/) is the
temporary/testing one. They look mostly the same now, but do not use exactly the same markup, CSS and JS.)

The problem is that I'm trying to make [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree) look more like what I had in the old
jQuery Treeview, and it won't cooperate. I spent an entire day on it yesterday,
and while I fixed many problems, I still have this one.

I tried using Firefox's Firebug, Opera's Dragonfly, and the equivalent tool in Google
Chromium has, but I lack the necessary skills to understand what goes wrong.

It appears that the jQuery Treeview authors tried to optimise performance by using a single image with a different `background-position` which makes it hard to debug, and I didn't get rid of it yet.

Any pinpoint to the problem, and/or a fix will be appreciated.

Comment: Try _line-height: 6px;height: 18px;_ for _.jqtree-tree li.jqtree-closed_ in your style

Comment: A.V: thanks for trying to help, but it appears to have matter a little worse (in my localhost copy): now the expander/collapser buttons still jump in Firefox, and, furthermore, I notice some gaps in the lines of the navigation menu, and now the text is jumpy too. In Opera, only the text jumps. Still have to try in Chromium.

Comment: Hi all, and happy holidays. Sorry to disappoint, but I rethought my strategy and decided to restart my CSS efforts starting from the existing style of the jqTree plugin, which works well enough, and to continue from there. After debugging a few minor CSS problems, I was able to get it work mostly fine. This is now live at the permanent (gamma) site: http://www.shlomifish.org/ . There are now some other enhancements there as well.

Comment: Thanks for everybody who tried to help.